# Simple batch file, if number = this echo hello, else echo world

Tags: batch-file

I am having trouble creating a simple batch file. All I want to be able to do it have do is generate a random number between 1 and 100 then if that number is less than or equal to 50 have it echo Hello and anything 51+ to echo World.

This is what I have:

```
        title Hello World

        set /a hw=%random% %%100 + 1
            if %hw% LEQ 50( 
                echo Hello
           )else(
                echo World
            )
        pause
```

I would also like this to run 5 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off&setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%i in (1,1,5) do (
title Hello World
set /a hw=!random! %%100 + 1
if !hw! LEQ 50 (
   echo Hello
) else (
   echo World
)
)
pause
```